# AND query against foreign key table in django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

Given:

```
class Video(models.Model):
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I know I can use `Video.objects.filter(tags__name__in=['foo','bar'])` to find all `Videos` that have either `foo` **OR** `bar` tags, but in order to find those that have `foo` **AND** `bar`, I'd have to join the foreign key twice (if I was handwriting the SQL). Is there a way to accomplish this in Django?

I've already tried `.filter(Q(tag__name='foo') & Q(tag__name='bar'))` but that just creates the impossible to satisfy query where a single `Tag` has both `foo` and `bar` as its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as straighfroward as it might look. Furthermore `JOIN`ing two times with the same table is typically not a good idea at all: imagine that your list contains ten elements. Are you going to `JOIN` ten times? This easily would become infeasible.

What we can do however, is count the overlap. So if we are given a list of elements, we first make sure those elements are unique:

```
tag_list = ['foo', 'bar']
tag_set = set(tag_list)
```

Next we count the number of tags of the `Video` that are actually in the set, and we then check if that number is the same as the number of elements in our set, like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Video.objects.filter(
    Q(tag__name__in=tag_set) | Q(tag__isnull=True)
).annotate(
    overlap=Count('tag')
).filter(
    overlap=len(tag_set)
)
```

Note that the `Q(tag__isnull-True)` is used to enable `Video`s *without* tags. This might look unnecessary, but if the `tag_list` is empty, we thus want to obtain *all* videos (since those have zero tags in common).

We also make the assumption that the names of the `Tag`s are *unique*, otherwise some tags might be counted twice.

Behind the curtains, we will perform a query like:

```
SELECT `video`.*, COUNT(`video_tag`.`tag_id`) AS overlap
FROM `video`
  LEFT JOIN `video_tag` ON `video_tag`.`video_id` = `video`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `tag` ON `tag`.`id` = `video_tag`.`tag_id`
WHERE `tag`.`name` IN ('foo', 'bar')
GROUP BY `video`.`id`
HAVING overlap = 2
```

Comment: I hadn't tried going the `annotate` route because I didn't realize you could use `filter` to generate `group by/having` SQL. Thanks. This is better than multiple joins